# Angular Chart Getting and Using Chart Data and Label Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am doing a angular chart, which has three values and labels for the display, when i click the chart it must show the label which i clicked. I am trying to get the values from points.

```js
 $scope.data = ["prospective","CallBacks","Closed"];
        $scope.labels = ["4","2","3"];
$scope.onClick = function (points,evt) {
    console.log("Points: "+JSON.stringify(points));
  $scope.struct=JSON.stringify(points);
  $scope.value=$scope.struct.label;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="pieChart" class="chart chart-pie"
     chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-click="onClick">
   </canvas>
<span>{{value}}</span>
```

Log show below Points:

```
[{"value":4,"outerRadius":95.5,"innerRadius":0,"fillColor":"rgba(151,187,205,0.8)","highlightColor":"rgba(151,187,205,0.8)","showStroke":true,"strokeWidth":2,"strokeColor":"#fff","startAngle":4.71238898038469,"circumference":1.9332877868244882,"label":"Prospective","_saved":{"value":4,"outerRadius":95.5,"innerRadius":0,"fillColor":"rgba(151,187,205,1)","highlightColor":"rgba(151,187,205,0.8)","showStroke":true,"strokeWidth":2,"strokeColor":"#fff","startAngle":4.71238898038469,"circumference":0,"label":"Prospective"},"endAngle":6.645676767209178}]
```

I can get values from log but which use the same in $scope.value the label is showing as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support guys, There were array of json it seems so when i give $scope.value=$scope.struct[0].label is working perfectly..